# Add id to elements in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im working on a wordpress site and right now a lot of elements has the same id which makes it difficult to customize.

Right now my solution is to add changes to all of the elements which isn't feasible, the difficult part is I am unsure of how to add an ID to the specific element.

Do I do this in the css file or do I edit in php somehow?

Or is it possible to add an ID with some plugin or similar?

Comment: It's pretty easy to just add a class or id to an element, for example a line of code could be `<p> hello world </p>` and with ID it would look like `<p id="example"> hello world </p>` and a class looks like `<p class="example2"> hello world </p>`, you can add to (I think) every HTML element.

Comment: In a default Wordpress installation with a common theme (i.e. one that has many installations) there are no duplicated ID's. Which theme do you use? And what kind of fancy plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @feeela I am using a "Cherry" theme, most of the elements have the same id on the home page which is driving me nuts and I can't find the css file that containts them.

The only plugin I use is a CSS editor plugin, which just shows the edit live and then I try to use the inspect tool of chrome.

Comment: @Jeremy yes I know how to do it, but I don't know where to find the code of the specific elements.

Comment: @feeela I found code that looks like this when I go to "edit page": [span4]
[su_spacer size="40"]
[su_posts posts_per_page="2" post_type="event" taxonomy="event-categories" tax_term="215" tax_operator="0" order="desc"]
[/span4] , Im unsure of what language it is and how to add an ID to it tho.

Comment: HTML element ID's are not set in CSS, but in HTML templates. Thus you may search forever in your CSS files without success. You should first read into the differences between content, design and behavior on websites and which language is used for what purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no short or easy answer to this.

The best way to figure out what's broken in your theme is by looking into the files it contains and how it works. I could not find the Cherry theme that you mentioned in your comment so that I could take a look.

Of course, to understand what's going on you're going to have to know a good amount about how themes are written. I can't suggest a better place to start than the [Codex article on theme development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). You may get better results (depending on how you learn best) from a web search for something like `wp building a theme`. I did and I got [this](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch) and [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/) but I learn best by reading; maybe videos will help you more. Unfortunately, you really won't be able to eliminate this step and it takes time.

Your theme most likely -- if it has been built in the WordPress way -- uses a series of included templates with the `get_template()` call. As you're looking, this is probably what you want to look for. I remember the first time I dissected a WP theme it was a daunting task and I had already been a very experienced developer for a long time at that point. Don't be discouraged.

Some themes and plugins use actions and filters to allow modification of their content. If your theme does this, modification could be as easy as hooking on a few of the right ones. This will still require figuring out which hooks to attach to.

I may be able to update this answer with something more specific if you point the first 5 or 10 hierarchical  children directly below the `<body>` element in a typical page, like your home page or your blog page.

If this seems too complicated, you're probably best to consider hiring someone who is more familiar with WordPress theme modification to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, embarrassingly enough I am working on a consulting firm, but it's student run and we have a ton of projects so sometimes we are forced to take on projects even though we have little to no experience in what we do (the customer know this).

It's only small changes the customer wants to be made but it's still a bit time consuming and frusttrating.

Comment: No worries. These things happen. I don't even like WordPress, I only started using it because a client _needed_ it. Post some HTML from your browser dev tool and I'll see what I can help with. Or point me to the theme (if it's public) and I'll tell you where to look.

Comment: sorry for the late answer and thank you for being helpful.
I manage to solve my issues and now the css parts is a bit easier actually.