# Hide 2 of the 3 item divs

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to hide 2 of the 3 item divs, the class name is **item**. I can usually use css display none, but they all have the same name, and its coming from WordPress plug in, and I believe its a template, so any changes made, it just replicates. Is there anyway I can add ID to each div which will automatically increment value by one, then I can use CSS display option?

```
<div class="related-post grid">
<div class="post-list">

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

</div>
 </div>
```

to

```
<div class="related-post grid">
<div class="post-list">

<div class="item" id="01">
</div>

<div class="item" id="02">
</div>

<div class="item" id="03">
</div>

</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can add whatever dynamic data you want with PHP, but not exactly like that, because ids should not be numeric. You could create `div`s with ids like `item1`, `item2` etc. in a loop with a counter.

Comment: To answer this we would need to know more detail about the plugin/theme you are using because they all work differently. Also check out this [Question/Answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632179/add-id-to-elements-in-wordpress)

Comment: you can do that in css surely using `nth-child` selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS pseudo classes to accomplish what you want:

```
.related-post .post-list .item:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

will hide any element with class `item` that is *not* the last element.

Or if you want to specifically target the first and second element:

```
.related-post .post-list .item:nth-child(1),
.related-post .post-list .item:nth-child(2)
{
  display: none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: This kind of worked, I was able to make changes to the the item divs like bgcolor changes, but display: none is not working, even when I add !important;

Comment: Then you might need more specificity, hang on. Edited my answer, see if that works

Comment: Thank you! That worked, excited to learn more about the "CSS pseudo classes"

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you could assign dynamically an id attribute to all the `.item` elements like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((i,n) => i.id = 'item_' + ++n);
```

```html
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
```